# how to fix frozen loading GIF on submit click for mobile,and fix loading GIF displayed on back click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have created a web page that has a form that prompts the user for two text-inputs and 1 radio-input. Once the user clicks submit, I have a function that is run OnClick that will use jQuery to hide() the form and show() the loading GIF.

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submitinput" onClick="loading();">
```

function

```
<script>

function loading(){
    $("#form1").hide();
    $("#loadingGIF").show();
}

</script>
```

On a desktop/laptop computer everything works fine (using Chrome for both), but on a tablet or phone (tested in Safari and Chrome) things go wrong. In the CSS stylesheet, I have the loading GIF set to display:none. I have tried to use the $(document).ready() function. I had the thought to have another function to maybe auto-refresh, but I'm not confident how to do that yet.

Comment: What goes wrong exactly? You haven't explained the problem

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. The issue is that when I click submit. I have a GIF that is a spinning circle. Upon clicking submit, it displays the GIF, but with no animation. It appears as a "snapshot" of what it should be doing. The second issue is that when I click the back arrow (after clicking submit and the page loads), the loading GIF is now displayed in full animation instead of showing the original form. I have read that this is because of cache. However, when using on a desktop/laptop, the GIF is animated upon clicking submit, and the back arrow, when clicked, goes back to the form.

Comment: I've noticed this before - I.E. on the desktop has a similar issue (or did for me), it seems to stop all animations when a form is submitted (on the grounds I suppose that the page is just about to be destroyed by the postback). I think it's just how some browsers do things. We tried all sorts to try and get round it but in the end I don't think we, as programmers, have any control over how the browser animates GIFs. Someone else may have found differently, but that was my experience

Comment: Thats interesting and a bit of a bummer since the GIF works great on a laptop/desktop.

Comment: Well, actually I'd probably say _"Works great on a laptop/desktop unless you use Internet Explorer or Safari (and maybe others which I haven't tested)"_. It's not so much the platform that's the determinant as the browser (and browser version).

Comment: But yes, it's a shame. We've just accepted that it looks a bit c**p in internet explorer - the company is switching to Chrome as default browser fairly soon anyway. N.B. On mobile we swapped the gif for a CSS animation which has a very similar effect

Comment: I understand, and appreciate the feedback. I will just bite the bullet on this one, and try to recreate my GIF